# Google Webapp permission

Tags: web-applications, permissions

I have a basic google web app that contains information for staff only. I need to deploy it so that only my staff organisational unit may view it. Currently all user from domain can see it. What is the best approach? Thank you all.

Comment: Are the users viewing it by url? Does the application know how is accessing the app? In other words do you have authentication in place? Are you logging in the users with a login name & password?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The users are view it by url. I have shared the url. I do not have an authentication method like username or password.